# go build while building C separately

Tags: c, go, linker

I have some Go code and some C code (quite a bit really).  I am calling the C code from the go code. Here is an example:

**test.h**

```c
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

void test();

#endif
```

**test.c**

```c
#include "test.h"

#include <stdio.h>

void test() {
    printf("Hello from C!")
}
```

**main.go**

```golang
package main

// #include "test.h"
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    C.test()
}
```

Imagine I have much more C code. This C code takes a while to compile. When compiling using `go build`, it recompiles the C every time. Is it possible to compile the C and go separately? Meaning that if I am working on the Golang code, I won't have to compile to C code?

I have tried linking the object files, but it seems very inefficient. If this is the best option? If so, could you provide a code example showing me how (as my way only works on Linux).

Comment: Maybe set up a build system with `make` or `ninja`?

Comment: Wouldn't this still make me recompile the C?

Comment: Not if you set it up right. Part of the purpose of such tools is that they support incremental compilation—that is, only compiling files that have been changed since the last time they were compiled.

Comment: Cool! Could you point me toward a site that gives me a rough outline on this? I have looked through the documentation (no very much though) and did some google searches but found nothing.

Comment: [Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), [Ninja manual](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html). They may be a bit dense, so google for more basic tutorials if you need.

Comment: I have googled and looked through both manuals. None mention using C and go.

Comment: Neither cares what languages you're using. Just set it up so the go file depends on the C object file, and the C object file depends on the C source. You may need to figure out the compiler flags to build go files one-at-a-time

Comment: The problem is that you still need a build tool for Go that `make` or `ninja` will run, and that will build a minimal unit without all the dependencies.  The whole point of the question is that `go build` doesn't do that for the OP.

Comment: Would that "minimal unit without all the dependencies" be an object file? Sorry for all  the questions.

Comment: If you are not familiar with make, a simpler build tool is https://taskfile.dev/. Section https://taskfile.dev/#/usage?id=prevent-unnecessary-work explains your use case. Regarding the proposed Ninja, I do not recommend to use it directly, it is too low-level. Use it via cmake. But again, taskfile is easier, although more verbose.

Comment: According to CGO page (https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) `... changes to files in other directories do not cause the package to be recompiled`

Comment: Did not see that! Must just be the linker. So sorry about this!